# Angular 8 - ng lint: Error in Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, lint

I have a problem with linting my project. 
Everytime I use "ng lint" following error appears:

```
$ ng lint
Linting "app"...
An unhandled exception occurred: Maximum call stack size exceeded
See "C:\Users\6100BR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-owDTzM\angular-errors.log" for further details.
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

However if I try to run the application or try to build it, everything works fine for me.

**Versions:**

- "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.2.0",
- "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
- "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
- "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
- "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
- "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
- "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta",
- "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
- "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.3.1",
- "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
- "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
- "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.3.0",
- "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.3.0",
- "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
- "angular-resizable-element": "^3.2.6",
- "jquery": "^3.4.1",
- "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
- "sass": "^1.23.0",
- "typescript": "~3.4.0",
- "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
- "zone.js": "~0.9.0"

Any idea how to resolve this or is there a way to find a more understandable error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add script to `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 --harmony node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng lint"
}
```

and execute:

```
npm run lint
```